# SQL Vulnerability - mod_rewrite

Tags: php, sql, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following modrewrite written in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/read/([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ ?i=f&p=t&cat=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I've been getting reports that there is a SQL vulnerability to this:

The read file looks like this:

```
$topicname = $_GET['id'];
$topicid = $_GET['id'];
$cat = $_GET['cat'];
$topicname = explode('-', $topicname);
$id = $topicname[0];
    //Get the data from the posts.
    $p = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT 
            p.*,
            u.*,
        FROM forum_posts p
        JOIN users u on u.id = p.userid
        WHERE topic_id=:id AND post_deleted='0'
        ORDER BY post_time ASC 
        LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage");
    $p->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $p->execute();
```

The report was:

```
You need to make the database not to get confused with the -> '
```

How can there be a vulnerability, when I use the `prepare()` statement?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your RewriteRule, but with your variable interpolation, if anything.

Comment: @mario How so? Where is the vulnerability? I've updated the code so the $_GET; requests are there too.